# YII2 - In test, send email nowhere

Tags: yii2

I have a test and live environment.  In test, I don't ever want to send the mailer mails.  I have the mailer setup as a component in web.php like this

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'nickcv\mandrill\Mailer',
        'apikey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'useMandrillTemplates' => true,
        'templateLanguage' => nickcv\mandrill\Mailer::LANGUAGE_HANDLEBARS,
    ],
```

Is there a way to set up the mailer component so it sends nowhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Because mailer you are using extends `yii\mail\BaseMailer` you can simply set its [`$useFileTransport`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-mail-basemailer#$useFileTransport-detail) to `true` and the mail will be saved in file instead.

```php
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'nickcv\mandrill\Mailer',
    'apikey' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'useMandrillTemplates' => true,
    'templateLanguage' => nickcv\mandrill\Mailer::LANGUAGE_HANDLEBARS,
    'useFileTransport' => true,
],
```

Another option is creating a [mock](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html) of mailer and using it instead of real mailer.

If you use codeception framework and its Yii2 module, the mailer component should be replaced automatically if you have `email` part enabled in codeception configs.

Answer (score 0):

======== Configure Apache to send the emails from localhost code ========

Changes for C:\xampp\php\php.ini file:

search for [mail function]:

```
[mail function]
SMTP=localhost to SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from=me@example.com to sendmail_from=your email address
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header=Off
mail.log = syslog
```

Changes for C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini:

search for [sendmail]:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=same as "sendmail_from" in php.ini file
auth_password=generated password for the email account
force_sender= same as "auth_username" in this file
```

=========== mailer component in Yii application ===============

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'your email address (for testing on localhost use same as in ini files)',
            'password' => 'generated password',
            'port' => 587,
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ], //end of mailer
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think it would be nice to receive somewhere your test emails for debugging and QA.

Personally, in dev environment, I would recommend setting up and configuring mailhog

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => '1025',
            ],
        ],
```

It is straightforward to install following the steps described here: https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog

You can then go to `http://localhost:8025` and see your inbox